# Usage of the possessive

Tags: possessives

Should the word " **bonus** " in the following sentence be written as possessive " bonuse**s'** "?

> Each element's value is a set of X,Y coordinate pairs of **bonuses'**
>   location

which means I have a field where bonuses are allocated:
[image]

and the set I'm talking about contains X,Y coordinate pairs of each circle:
{(30,30),(30,90),...}

Comment: I don't think it would take the possessive, but I don't really understand what "of bonus" means in that sentence.  An X,Y pair identifies a location in a plane, e.g. a pixel, but how does "bonus" come into it?

Comment: Is there any reason to assume that this instance of "bonus" is a noun?  Although many dictionaries define it as such, my native understanding of the word defaults to an adjective interpretation, similar to "extra" or "additional".

Comment: It's unlikely that bonus would ever take a possessive marking. Also, it might help if we understood it!

Comment: Sorry for incomplete information, I updated the question

Answer (score 1):

If the phrase means that each pair could be in a different location then the plural belongs with location -- i.e. locations.

If the phrase means that there is more than one bonus per tuple then it should be "bonuses."

If it indeed it is a plural possessive then it should be "bonuses' location."

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about plural. I updated the question, could you have a look again, please?

Comment: It looks correct, but may still be confusing to the average user. It may be better to rewrite the sentence to: All of the bonuses for each tuple are located at the indicated X,Y coordinate/s. (I used the /s construction because it is still not clear if there is more than one location. : )